# multiple graphs in one instance

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm making view of my switch with cytoscape. Switch has about 40 ports, each port fits nice to the breadthfirst layout.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddg2D.png

But I need around 40 about same graphs in one page

When I'm using breadthfirst with multiple roots I'm getting mess like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYcNz.png

So, can I deal with this somehow?

Sorry, dont have 10 rep yet, so cant paste images and more links to explain more correctly.

Also english not my native language.

Comment: jsbin http://jsbin.com/jijayawave/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run different layouts on different parts of the graph, if you want to keep all elements in a single instance: http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/layout

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this example?: 
http://jsbin.com/gist/310dca83ba6970812dd0?js,output

It is basically the same that you want to do. Just add in your body tag:

```
<body>
    <div id="cyFirstInstance"></div>
    <div id="cySecondInstance"></div>
</body>
```

And in your javascript function where you define the nodes, add for each instance the style (it could be the same for both nodes)

```
$('#cyFirstInstance').cytoscape({
    style: ...

$('#cySecondInstance').cytoscape({
    style: ...
```

Hope this helps.